# Recover tree from given traversals

Tags: data-structures, tree

If we have given either in-order and pre-order or in-order and post-order traversals, then can we recover any type of tree ? for example **Binary Search Tree (BST), Complete Tree, Full Tree, General Binary Tree**

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes with in-order and pre-order traversal of binary trees.**

For example, with in-order L1 = [4, 2, 3, 5, 1] and pre-order L2 = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]:

1. the root is 3 (first element of pre-order)
2. the in-order traversal of the left sub tree is [4, 2] (elements before 3 in L1) and the pre-order traversal of the left sub tree is [2, 4] (must use the same elements as the in-order)
3. find recursively the left sub-tree and similarly the right sub-tree.

**No with pre-order and post-order.**

The two possible trees with two vertices have the same pre-order and post-order traversal.